# Domo ryuu login does not work: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: domo

I am building a Domo custom app and the domo auth process is managed by the npm package ryuu. When launching my app locally, I get this error:

`error: {status: 401, statusReason: "Unauthorized", path: "/domoapps/apps/v2/contexts", message: "Full authentication is required to access this resource"}`

I have ADMIN rights in my Domo instance, so this should not be the problem. How to I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a temporary fix: ryuu was in version 3, I uninstalled it and reverted it to version 2:

`npm uninstall -g ryuu
npm i -g ryuu@2.23.22`

The login process now happens in the CLI and not through the web interface which seems to make a difference. This needs to be fixed in version 3.

The Domo Dojo corresponding feed I opened: https://dojo.domo.com/t5/Domo-Developer/Ryuu-auth-does-not-work/m-p/34372/highlight/false#M935